# Swift, Inference and protocol behavior

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have recently downloaded xCode 6 and have been playing about with Swift language. So far, I am enjoying it. I was reading up on Swift features, and one of them which I quite like is inference. However in a code sample I created to practice creating protocols in Swift, I am getting an issue I don't quite understand so was hoping someone would help clarify what is going on. Perhaps I am missing something. So to the code sample

I created a protocol Animal

```
protocol Animal
{
   func speak()
}
```

Then I created a Dog and Cat class which conforms to the animal protocol, e.g.

```
class Dog: Animal {

    func speak()
    {
        println("Woof");
    }
}
```

Then I created dog and cat variables to check it was working as expected

```
    var animal1 = Dog()
    var animal2  = Cat()

    println(animal1.speak())
    println(animal2.speak())
```

No issues so far. So then I decided to add these to an array and loop through the objects and print them out

```
 var ar = [animal1, animal2];

        for var i = 0; i < ar.count; i++
        {
            var an = ar[i]

            println(an.speak())
        }
```

However I am getting an error saying "AnyObject does not conform to protocol "Animal" as well as a warning saying "Variable an inferred to have type "AnyObject" which may be unexpected. I thought due to inference, it should automatically realize Dog and Cat conform to Animal protocol. When I was printing the speak method previously, I didn't need to specify Animal type. So Then I updated the variable within the loop method so it explicitly states that the object conforms to Animal type like so

```
var an : Animal = ar[i]
```

This removes the warning, however the error persists. Why is this the case? I have explicitly told it that this object conforms to the Animal protocol. I can do this in Objective-c without an issue like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
    {
        id <Animal> an = [ar objectAtIndex:i];
        [an speak];
    }
```

So why doesn't this work in Swift?

I then updated the original declaration of animal1 and animal2, so it looks like this

```
var animal1 : Animal = Dog()
var animal2  = Cat()
```

Or I can do this

```
var animal1 = Dog()
    var animal2 : Animal = Cat()
```

And the error is gone. Why do I only need to update one of the variables to state that conforms to protocol Animal, and not both?

Would be grateful if someone would clarify what is going on here? Maybe I am just missing something

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift there's single inheritance (a class can inherit from one class only), but multiple protocol adoption.

Type inference cannot figure out what's in common between Cat and Dog because they do not inherit from the same class. If you turn Animal into a class, your loop works fine.

A class can implement multiple protocols, and 2 classes can have more than one protocol in common. Since type inference cannot choose one of them when determining which type to assign to the array, it chooses to make it `Array<AnyObject>`.

To fix the problem, just make the array type explicit:

```
var ar: [Animal] = [animal1, animal2]
```

`animal1` and `animal2`, regardless of their actual type, are both instances of classes implementing the `Animal` protocol.

In this code:

```
var animal1 : Animal = Dog()
var animal2  = Cat()
```

you are providing the compiler enough info to let type inference determine the array type: `animal1` has `Animal` type, `animal2` is an instance of `Cat`, which in turns implements that protocol

Comment: Objective-c also has multiple protocol adoption however and does not have this problem. As a test, I quickly created random protocol in Objc-C, and added it to the cat class, but not the dog class. In Obj-c however, I can check if a class conforms to a protocol, can something similar be done in Swift?

Comment: You can check with `is`. For example, `if dog is Animal`. Even better you can do a cast that return optional value containing some value if cast was successful or nil if it wasn't successful. For example, `var dog = arr[0] as? Dog`

Comment: In obj-c it works because it doesn't use generics, so the compiler doesn't try to enforce a type check for the elements in the array. In swift instead they must be of the same type, or inherit/implement from a common ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason array is not inferred as `Animal` is because classes can conform to multiple protocols but only inherit from one class. In case your `Cat` and `Dog` also conformed to protocol like `Pet` how would you know whether to infer to `Animal` or `Pet` array.

In your case just declare explicit type array:

```
var ar: [Animal] = [animal1, animal2]

for var i = 0; i < ar.count; i++
{
    var an = ar[i]
    println(an.speak())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we should inferred array as Animal, how above said, Please have a look at this too

In your case just declare explicit type array:

```
var array: [Animal] = [animal1, animal2]

for animal in array 
{
    if let an = animal is Dog {
    print(" Hey! Dog speaking:\(an.speak())")
  } if let an = animal is Cat {
    print(" Hey! Cat speaking:\(an.speak())")
  }

}
```